# Iterated limits and directional limits - solution

Tags: calculus, limits

I have to decide if the following limit is convergence, using iterated  limits, and getting the same result by using directional limits.

$\lim _{(x,y,z)\to (1,1,1)}(2 x - y + z - 2)/(x + y - z - 1) $

In the case of the directional limits, I know how to do them with too variables, but I get lost when I have three. I try to calculate them, but I get that none of the three different iterated limits exists. Is that possible? In this case, what can I conclude?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why do you think that the limit exists?

Comment: What three different iterated limits are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=y\to1, z=x^2\to1$,

$$(2 x - y + z - 2)/(x + y - z - 1)= (x +x^2 - 2)/(2x -x^2 - 1)=-\frac{x+2}{x-1}$$

the limit doesn't exist

Comment: And how can I do by iterative limits? Do I have to calculate first the limit  when $z \to 1$, or can I directly calculate $z\to 1, y\to 1$?